# Wordpress Functions File Printing Code To Top Of Website

Tags: php, wordpress, function

i am following a html to wordpress tutorial and having issues with the functions.php file.

The test website is - http://e37.369.myftpupload.com

The functions.php file is printing out to the top of the website, and i have no 'widgets'  or 'menu' option in the wordpress back end.

All that is in the functions.php file is this

```
function register_my_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('menu', __('Menu'));
}
add_action('init', 'register_my_menu');
```

Comment: Please provide ALL relevant code. You're missing something here, i.e. an echo/print instead of a return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i forgot to wrap the above code in php tags!

fixed!
I'm a moron